# cppmanをtmuxの左ペインに開き、閉じる際にレイアウトを崩さない方法

Tags: vim, tmux

neovimとtmuxを使用しています。c++でコードを書く際にcppmanでドキュメントを確認したく思ったので、https://stackoverflow.com/a/30373736を参考に

```
 autocmd FileType cpp set keywordprg=cppman
 command! -nargs=+ Cppman silent! call system("tmux split-window -bh cppman " . expand(<q-args>))
 autocmd FileType cpp nnoremap <silent><buffer> K <Esc>:Cppman <cword><CR>
 autocmd FileType cpp vnoremap <silent><buffer> K <Esc>:Cppman <cword><CR>
```

をinit.vimに追加して利用しています。しかしこの方法では、もともと横並びに2つのペインが並んでいる場合には
(0、1が元のペイン、1からcppmanを実行すると2にcppmanが開く)

```
 cppman利用前    cppman利用中     cppman利用後
  _________      __________     _________
 | |       |    | |   |   |    |     |   |
 |0|   1   | -> |0| 2 | 1 | -> |  0  | 1 |
 |_|_______|    |_|___|___|    |_____|___|
```

のようにレイアウトが崩れてしまいます。tmuxのヘルプを見た所hookは使えそうかと思い

```
1. tmux set-hook pane-exited "swap-pane"
2. tmux set-hook -u pane-exited
```

を処理に挟みたいと考えたのですが、これ以上は分かりませんでした。これら(あるいはそれ以外)の方法でうまく動かす方法はありますでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

かなり無理やりですが、まず以下の内容のtmux-cppmanというファイルをPATHが通っているどこかに作成して実行権を付与し、

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ -z "$TMUX_LAYOUT" ]; then
    layout=$(tmux list-windows -F "#{window_layout} #{window_active}" | awk '/ 1$/ {print $1}')
    tmux split-window -bh env TMUX_LAYOUT=$layout $0 "$@"
else
    cppman "$@"
    tmux kill-pane \; select-layout $TMUX_LAYOUT
fi
```

vimからはこのtmux-cppmanを呼ぶようにする

```
command! -nargs=+ Cppman silent! call system("tmux-cppman " . expand(<q-args>))
```

というのはどうでしょうか。

戦略としては、まずlist-windowsで現在のlayoutを確認して覚えておき、cppmanが終了した後にselect-layoutでそのlayoutに戻すという物です。
スクリプトを二重に起動したりしているので、もっとシンプルになればいいんですけれど……

Comment: 無事動きました。ありがとうございます。cppman側に何かしらのスクリプトを仕込まないといけないかと思っていましたが、レイアウトを取り出し、復元する方法があるのですね。勉強になりました。